# Creating registration links

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter, md5, registration

I have the following code igniter model function, but it is returning a strange link, not sure how to handle it:

```
        function create_registration_links ()
    {
        $sql = 'update users_csv_import
                set reg_link = md5(username)
                where reg_link is null';

        $this->db->query($sql);
    }
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Error Number: 1406

Data too long for column 'reg_link' at row 25

update users_csv_import set reg_link = md5(username) where reg_link is null
```

Comment: what is the datatype for reg_link field,,, give your table structure...

Comment: Set reg_link field type VARCHAR and length = 32